# how to shuffle a large list of items in parallel, python

Tags: python, algorithm, shuffle, bigdata

I have the bottleneck in my calculations on python: I need to shuffle a large list (`~10^9` elements).
Current implementation:

```
import random
random.shuffle(list)
```

With this method, only one core is involved. Is it possible to shuffle a large list in parallel?

Comment: it takes 47 minutes now

Comment: Can you write a random number generator that runs in parallel and produces unique results covering a range? E.g. all threads combined produce all possible results, but none of them overlap. Oh, and all of them have the same probability distribution over the entire range.

Comment: How are you consuming the shuffled list? Would something that produced results incrementally fit your use case?

Comment: @mwchase, I'm going to send shuffled list by batches to word2vec ML algo using tensorflow lib

Comment: @YannVernier, yes I think I can do it

Comment: That's basically the answer. If you can do that then each of those threads produces one of your batches. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem easy to me; the non-overlapping but complete part is easy if you can just partition, but that violates the equal distribution. My first thought doesn't run in parallel but just selects a random thread to send each item to sequentially, letting the threads shuffle incoming items.

Comment: I wonder if using incremental Fisher-Yates (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) and pulling out the results every `batchsize` iterations would speed things up any. It'd still require a single-threaded shuffle, but the processing would happen in parallel with the shuffle.

Comment: It takes 47 minutes to shuffle 10^9 items? That seems excessive. Just what are these items you're shuffling? Are you shuffling in memory or on disk? @mwchase has a good idea.

Comment: @JimMischel, in RAM, the data has format: [(1,2),(3,4),(7,3), ...etc]

Comment: @JimMischel, funny thing: it takes 47 minutes on 64CPU, 400Gb RAM machine :)))) Thats's why I would like to parallelize the task

Comment: Funny thing: On my system, a 3.5 GHz machine with 32 GB of RAM, it takes less than five minutes to do a shuffle of 1 billion `Point` structures (`struct Point {int x; int y}`) That's in C#, single-threaded, debug build. A release build does it in about a minute and a half. I can't imagine that C# is 20 times faster than Python.

Comment: Maybe there's some kind of threshold beyond which performance drops? I'm messing around on a 2 GHz MacBook Air with 8GB RAM, and up to 10^7, it seems linear with an acceptable factor (~7 seconds for 10^7, which would imply ~12 minutes for 10^9, which is, I think, not bad), and then things start to go bad by 10^8. Maybe it's hitting memory limits. I can compare later with the beefier laptop.

Comment: I think the threshold is "list does not fit in RAM". No idea what's up with the list on your machine, but it looks to me like the non-linearity comes from the list object being larger than the total RAM.

Answer (score 2):

You may check the [Process](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#the-process-class) class, which can be exemplified in this way:

```
import random
from multiprocessing import Process


def worker_func(variable_1):
# your code

random.shuffle(list_single)

if __name__ == '__main__':
#Create a process list 
process_list = list()

pid = os.getpid()
print('Main Process is started and PID is: ' + str(pid))

#Start Process
list_example = [[1,2,3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
for list_single in list_example:
    p = Process(target=worker_func, args=(list_single, ))
    p.start()
    child_pid = str(p.pid)
    print('PID is:' + child_pid)
    process_list.append(child_pid)
    child = multiprocessing.active_children()

while child != []:
    time.sleep(1)
    child = multiprocessing.active_children()
```

If you want to run this data in parallel, you can use [multithreading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) or [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing). You should define your worker function and call it in the process.

Comment: You suggest splitting the list into sublist, shuffle sublists in parallel and union the sublists?

Comment: Yeah, that can be one solution ;)

Comment: There's something wrong with the code indentation. Stuff at the top level is outside the code blocks.

Comment: Multiprocessing has a ton of communication overhead. This probably wouldn't actually save time.